# How to accomplish PHP crypt function in Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js

Our backend password is generated by PHP `crypt` function

```
var pwd = crypt(value, salt)
```

As salt is formatted in such way: $2a$05&aabbccdd, I assume at the backend of crypt, it's using blowfish algorithm, so is there any way I can accomplish crypt function in Nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

[node-crypt3](https://github.com/sendanor/node-crypt3) looks a little old but should be mostly usable AFAIK.

```
var crypt = require('crypt3');

var pwd = crypt(value, salt);
```

Comment: I tried it just few hours before, anyway it's not that old(last updated about a month), but the result is totally different from what I want... I may try writing a PHP API to handle this. Waste too much time already, thanks anyway

Comment: @klamtlne: In what way is it different? Both delegate to `crypt(3)`.

Comment: the final result. crypt(3) generates something like: $2g.ntzcx, as the real result is a long string with numbers start and characters.

Comment: What salt did you pass?

Answer (score 0):

So for those who still fighting to get a working version for 8+, I created a new module forked out of this one, with newer dependencies:

`npm i --save @idango/crypt3`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@idango/crypt3